# Fit all nav items in nav with equal width and no wrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a nav menu with 15 elements. The elements must have equal width (which I achieved using `nav-justified` but when I resize the window, the menu keeps shrinking (expected behavior) until one point it stops and goes out of the screen.

Code ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9fsc8ko/3/)):

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified flex-nowrap">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 1</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 2</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 3</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 4</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 5</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 6</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 7</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 8</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 9</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 10</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 11</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 12</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 13</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 14</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Item 15</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you applay `min-width` for example with 1px the elements should shrink more

```
li, a {
   min-width: 1px;
}
```

Also set overflow to no horicontal scrolling